# Triggering focusout() events from other focusout() event

Tags: jquery

am using a focus out event for one validation in jquery.
like

`$("#A").focusout(function ()`

here 'A' is the id of the textbox

the function contains a set of statements.
I need to call the same function for another text box's focus out function.
How can i trigger like that?
Please help me out
Thanks in advance

Comment: $("#anotherTextBox").trigger("focusout")

Answer (score 2):

This should help you out:

```
$("#myTextBox").trigger("focusout");
```